# глюки Qt и Qt Creator

Tags: qt5, qtcreator

Имеется Qt Creator 4.4.0, Qt 5.9.1, система Windows 7x64

Все работало, после одной неудачной компиляции проекта - Qt вываливает больше 1000 (а если точнее 1287) ошибок и почти 11000 проблем на любом Qt проекте, не работают даже родные примеры. Везде ругается на свои внутренние компоненты (типа

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\mingw53_32\include\QtCore\qobjectdefs.h:144: ошибка: return type 'class QString' is incomplete { return staticMetaObject.tr(s, c, n); },
C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\mingw53_32\include\QtCore\qmap.h:112: ошибка: 'QMapNode<Key, T>::key' has incomplete type Key key;),
```

и так на все, что имеет отношение к Qt. Нормально собираются и работают только консольные приложения.
кто с таким встречался? как побороть?

п.с. переустанавливать среду не предлагать - это крайний случай. Хотелось бы найти решение без переустановки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После долгих поисков, решение кроме как переустановить Qt, так и не было найдено